# Cassandra is not updating data with CQL, with mutator it does

Tags: cassandra, cql, hector

With the following code I try to update a row

```
Keyspace fKeyspace = HFactory.createKeyspace(KEYSPACE, fCluster);

// Update with CQL
CqlQuery<String,String,String> cqlQuery =
   new CqlQuery<String,String,String>(fKeyspace, fStringS, fStringS, fStringS);
cqlQuery.setQuery(
    "INSERT INTO Fahrer (KEY, 'first') VALUES('fahrer1', 'FirstnameUpdated')");
QueryResult<CqlRows<String,String,String>> result = cqlQuery.execute();

// Update with mutator
Mutator<String> mutator = HFactory.createMutator(fKeyspace, fStringS);
MutationResult mr = mutator.insert("fahrer2", "Fahrer",
   HFactory.createStringColumn("first", "SecondUpdated"));
```

The update of the CQL-query is not performed, the update with the mutator is performed. Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to have your key and column name transposed. For keys you have:
"fahrer2" on the mutator and "first" on the CQL query.

If you have not already, please see the following for more on CQL in Hector (and in general):
https://github.com/rantav/hector/wiki/Using-CQL

Comment: Thank you for that hint! I use two different keys to test two different rows... otherwise the mutator would "hide" the changing of the CQL-string. Both rows have the column "first". I've read through the whole Hector wiki but there are still questions left... and it would be nice to have a JavaDoc-API available ^^